# PCB Corrosion Clean Up

Tags: corrosion

Any advice on cleaning up this PCB corrosion or fixing this board?

[image]

This is on a CR-814 stereo form a 1994 Volvo 940.

Audio is fine when the stereo is powered on.  After a few seconds the front right speaker clicks at ~ 1 Hz.  The frequency of the click occurrence increases slowly till it becomes a high pitched whine.  The whine increases in frequency, then after maybe 20 minutes it becomes inaudible all of a sudden and audio is fine.

Perhaps some flux didn't get cleaned up.  Maybe a component leaked?  I don't know what the 3 legged "50" component is.  The rest of the boards look fine, and the enclosure is well built and intact.  The problem area is in the center of a protective bit.

The black corrosion has a liquid component.  A gentle touch with a screwdriver pulls the sludge off.  I find the white corrosion on the solder very interesting.

My best guess would be to dam the area to prevent collateral damage, and scrub with isopropyl alcohol 90%.  I'd hope this removes any shorts that are occurring between components through the liquid.  Maybe I'd find a fully corroded solder joint.

Comment: @Rodo Don't answer questions in the comment section.

Comment: I would search for a damaged electrolytic capacitor or some other liquid/gel filled component.

Answer (score 0):

That looks more like the circuit is overheating. I see what looks like tiny droplets of solder. Try cleaning it with the alcohol and a stiff brush so you can get a better look at the circuit traces, but I suspect you'll find a component has gone bad. As @RussellH said, you may have a defective electrolytic capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

Try IPA if that doesn't work get some tech-spray flux remover which is a good solvent for cleaning PCBs.

A little acetone could also get it but also damage parts on the PCB so be careful.